# Python: Strange output for threaded ARP ping

Tags: python, multithreading, output, arp

thanks for taking the time to look at this!

The issue I'm having is with the output of my threaded ARP script. What I'm trying to achieve is to have the IP address, MAC address and NIC vendor of each alive host output to command prompt.

I have an older ARP script without threading, which takes around 90 seconds and prints my ideal output.

Below is my newer script, based off of the aforementioned script, with threading. Unfortunately, I have no idea why there are no values being shown in the output. If anybody can help I will be extremely grateful!

Thanks in advance!

```
def arp2(ip):

    # An ARP scanner for the network.
    ips = []

    global ans, unans
    ans, unans = srp(Ether(dst="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff")/ARP(pdst=ip), timeout=2, verbose=0)

    for snd, rcv in ans:
    #Assign MAC address and IP address to variables mac and ipaddr

        mac = rcv.sprintf(r"%Ether.src%")
        ipaddr = rcv.sprintf(r"%ARP.psrc%")

        #Get NIC vendor code from MAC address
        niccode = mac[:8]
        niccode = niccode.upper()

        print ips
        ips.append("end")

        #ARPips file amendments
        with open( 'C:\Python26\ARPips.prn', 'w+') as f:
            f.write("\n".join(map(lambda x: str(x), ips)) + "\n")

        #String lookup for NIC vendors. DO NOT CHANGE 'r' TO ANY OTHER VALUE.
        with open('C:\Users\TomVB\Desktop\OID2.prn', 'r') as file:
            for line in file:
                if niccode in file:
                    return mac, ipaddr, line[8:]




def main():

    print "Discovering..."
    print ""
    print "MAC Address \t \t  IP Address \t  NIC Vendor"


    pool = Pool(processes=12)

    Subnetlist = []

    for i in range(255):
        Subnetlist.append(str(IPInt+str(i)))

    global ARPresults
    ARPresults = pool.map(arp2, Subnetlist)

    pool.close()
    pool.join()


    print "\n".join(ARPresults)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This script gives me the following output:

```
Mac Address    IP address      NIC Vendor

[][]

[]

[]

[]
 []
[][]
[]

[]
```

and so on like this for around 200 lines.

Comment: [reread my answer to your previous question. The issues are similar](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22330003/4279)

Comment: Hey @J.F.Sebastian, thanks for looking at this, I thought this when I wrote this script. Do you know why its not printing even though mac and ipaddr are returned and map picks them up? I feel like I'm missing something really obvious ):

Comment: the first issue in the previous question: `ping()` doesn't return anything but you are trying to print its results. Does `arp2()` return anything?

Comment: unrelated: to help you learn: 1. remove `global` from your code (you don't need it) 2.a Do not overwrite the same file `ARPips.prn` in multiple processes. At the best only one process will manage to write the results. 2.b Don't print in child processes, return all results to the parent process and write to a file and print there.

Comment: Thanks for the tips @J.F.Sebastian, equally as valuable as getting the right answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, it looks like your you're using multi-processing and not threading. Those two behave quite differently and I suggest you look into that. Anyway, for the problem at hand, the cause is elsewhere.

The `arp2` method is executed in parallel. I see two problems in that method:

```
print "%s \t  %s  \t  %s" % (mac, ipaddr, line[8:])
```

This statement prints to standard-output. In our code it might be executed by up to 12 processes simultaneously. Python gives you no gurantees that the `print` statement is atomic. It might very well happen that one process has written half the line when the next process writes his line. In short, you get a mess in the output.

The same holds for

```
with open( 'C:\Python26\ARPips.prn', 'w+') as f:
    f.write("\n".join(map(lambda x: str(x), ips)) + "\n")
```

Again there are no guarantees that the processes won't step on each others toes. The file content might get scambled.

The easiest solution is not to do any file or console output inside the `arp2` method. Instead return the results. `pool.map` will collect those results for you in a safe manner. It behaves like the regular `map` function. Then you can output them to files and console.

If you want output while the scan is running you have to synchronize the processes(for example with `multiprocessing.Lock`. So that only one process is ever writing/printing at the same time.

Also:

- Put an 'r' in front of string literals with windows-style paths: `x = r'C:\Users\TomVB\Desktop\OID2.prn'`. Backslashes are used for escaping in Python.
- Load the content of `C:\Users\TomVB\Desktop\OID2.prn` into a `dict`. It will be much faster.
- `map(lambda x: str(x), ips)`  is equal to `map(str, ips)`

Comment: Hi @Stefan Thank you very much for your reply! I really appreciate your time looking into this with me. 

With regards to your answer, I altered this statement:

 print "%s \t  %s  \t  %s" % (mac, ipaddr, line[8:])

to this: 

return mac, ipaddr, line[8:]

yet where the output would normally be, for example:

[5]    [3]    [1]    [2]    [4]  
[1]    [5]    [2]    [4]    [5]

The output is still similar to this: 

[][]
[]

[] 
[][][]  etc.. 

Any idea why this might be occurring?

Comment: Please show the actual code that you are using. What you describe does not match your code. If your only change is to return a tuple, then `ARPresults` will be a list of tuples. `print "\n".join(ARPresults)` will throw an error. Also pls clean up unused code like `hostID += 1`.

Comment: Hi @Stefan, I've made some changes, the statement: 
print "\n".join(ARPresults)
Doesn't throw an error, but perhaps its the reason why there are no values being shown? Thanks for your advice again :)

Comment: I still cannot see how that code produces that output. Does `srp`, `ARP`, or `Ether` produce any output? Please remove `global ans, unans`, you could probably get away with it here, but when running things in parallel you do not one process to change the content of a variable of another process. You realize that everything after `return` wont be executed if the entry is found in the file? `ips` has no use I can see. I repeat: do not use `print` or `write` in parallel code without protection. Please reduce code to the minimum required to demonstrate your problem.

Comment: Hi @stefan, thanks a bunch for bearing with me haha. Had a hazzah moment this morning. The mistake was indeed really stupid, but incase you were wondering, error was twofold. 

the print ips statement, was printing an empty list several times, while the line 'if niccode in file' should have been 'if niccode in line'. by altering these two the output was as it should be.

Thanks again for looking at this with me! :P

Comment: My pleasure. Thanks for telling me, I was indeed curious :) I was under the assumption that you had removed the print-line (you should) and I really didn't see the `niccode in file` bug.