# Python Subprocess wait for a list of subprocess

Tags: python, bash, concurrency, subprocess

I am using python3 subprocess module to cope with bash script call. I want to control the number of concurrent subprocess when calling the script.

> Popen.wait(timeout=None)
>   Wait for child process to terminate. Set and return returncode attribute.

I know that I can call the subprocess.Popen.wait(timeout=None) to wait for child process to terminate. But I was wondering about if I can wait for a list of subprocess.Popen to finish, with that, I can control the number of concurrent processes.

Sample code snippets as following:

Example.py

```
import subprocess
from itertools import zip_longest

seed = [1, 2, 4, 1, 3, 5, 4, 1]
basepath="/path/to/file/hello.sh"

def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)

def bash_handler(num):
    return subprocess.Popen('bash {0} {1}'.format(basepath, num), shell=True)

for bulk in grouper(seed, 2):
    [bash_handler(item).wait() for item in bulk if item is not None]
# This will executed one by one
```

hello.sh

```
# Validation goes here.
echo $1
sleep $1
echo "Finish Executed"
```

Comment: you can use `communicate()`

Comment: @MaheshKaria No idea how can I use it. Any help or helpful threads?

Comment: Oops, I didn't really mean to close as duplicate (didn't realize this was also tagged [tag:bash]). I'll be happy to reopen if the current duplicate doesn't solve your problem, or at least look for a different duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

when you use communicate(), you don't need to  specify the wait for the subprocess to exit. more information can be found here https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html
other link
[Understanding Popen.communicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16768290/understanding-popen-communicate)

below changes should work for you

```
from subprocess import Popen,PIPE
def bash_handler(num):
    return subprocess.Popen('bash {0} {1}'.format(basepath, num), shell=True,stdout=PIPE)


for bulk in grouper(seed, 2):
    [bash_handler(item).communicate() for item in bulk if item is not None]
```

Comment: Running `bash` with `shell=True` is ... wacky. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess

Comment: @pankaj mishra Notice that I want the subprocess in `bulk` to run simultaneously. Is there any way to achieve this? Or I just need to switch to  the multiprocessing module?

Comment: @tripleee  could be the right person to answer this

Comment: `Popen` by default runs separate processes, they will essentially churn on in the background if you don't need to `communicate()` specifically with them. Use `subprocess.poll()` to examine the status without blocking.