# python: proc.comunicate hangs

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm trying to start another script in python and then give an answer to input, this is the main script:

```
import subprocess
import sys
import platform

cmdline = ['py', 'ciao.py']
cmd = subprocess.Popen(cmdline, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
for line in cmd.stdout:
    if line == b'Loading...\r\n':
        print("sending data...")
        cmd.communicate(b"test\n")[0]
        print("done")
    print(line)
print(line)
```

And this is **ciao.py**:

```
import os
import re
import time
print("Loading...")
ciao = input("> ")
print(ciao)
os.system("mkdir okfunziona")
print("Done")
while 1:
    time.sleep(10)
```

The main script manages to send `"test"` but then hangs and does not print `"done"` to the console.

The problem is both on windows and on linux.

**---------------------------------------------------------------EDIT--------------------------------------------------------------**
Ok i have tested Ashish Nitin Patil's example but i see `b'Loading...\r\n'` output,  and I do not see the other outputs of the secondary script, like `">"` or `"Done"`, it seems that the `"cmd.stdout.readline ()"` works only the first time because the script does not end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this answer (and others on that question)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16769956/2689986) for inspiration. For your case, you should **not** be using `communicate`, instead use `stdin.write` and `stdout.readline`.

Your main script might look like below -

```
while True:
    line = cmd.stdout.readline()
    print(line)
    if line.strip() == b'Loading...':
        print("sending data...")
        cmd.stdin.write(b"test\n")
        cmd.stdin.close()
        print("done")
    elif line.strip() == b'Done':
        break
```

The outputs -

```
b'Loading...\n'
sending data...
5
done
b'> test\n'
b'Done\n'
```

Comment: thanks but the output is only:
b'Loading...\r\n'
sending data...
done
It seems that the cmd.stdout.readline() works only the first time

Comment: You are most likely stuck because `ciao.py` errs when `os.system('mkdir' ...)` would fail because of "file exists" error. Try putting it in an `if` statement, e.g. `if not os.path.exists('okfunziona'): os.system('mkdir okfunziona')`

Comment: Wow, I've always focused on the main script and I had not really thought about it, THANK YOU A THOUSAND