# Python printing bytes string directly to printer on Linux

Tags: python, linux, printing, reportlab

A temp file can print by using

```
subprocess.run(["lp", "-d", "<printer>", tmp])
```

But is it possible to print a bytes string representing a ReportLab generated pdf?

```
buffer = BytesIO()
c = canvas.Canvas(buffer)
c.drawString(100, 100, "Hello World")
c.showPage()
c.save()

pdf = buffer.getvalue()
lpr = subprocess.Popen("/usr/bin/lpr", stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
lpr.stdin.write(pdf)
buffer.close()
```

This code starts a print job but with a size of `0k` and a status of Held.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are missing a `lpr.communicate()` call, compare with:
[Understanding Popen.communicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16768290/understanding-popen-communicate?answertab=votes#tab-top)