# Using subprocess in Python, I get different results when in Python cmd and Python IDLE

Tags: python, command-line, subprocess

I hope the title makes sense. To give specifics:

I am using csvtotable (https://github.com/vividvilla/csvtotable) to generate HTML tables from CSVs. I have installed via pip and am able to run a command line command:

```
csvtotable test1743.csv test1743.html
```

to generate a HTML page. All good so far.

I wanted to do this from within a Python script I had already written so I heard that subprocess was the way to do this. I looked up how to do it and understood that it can be done using the following:

```
subprocess.run('csvtotable test1743.csv test1743.html',shell=True)
```

So I tested this via the command line first by doing

```
python
```

from the command line and then running

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run('csvtotable test1743.csv test1743.html',shell=True)
```

Success! It worked. Fantastic.

However, when I try to do this from IDLE, it just returns a 1.  I have checked the directory thinking that maybe the csv was missing from there, but it still doesn't work.

Am I misunderstanding how subprocess works?

Comment: have you tried `subprocess.run(["csvtotable", "test1743.csv", "test1743.html"], shell=True)`?

Comment: @GuiGWR I just tried it and unfortunately it returns `CompletedProcess(args=['csvtotable', 'test1743.csv', 'test1743.html'], returncode=1)`. I will play around with input and output arguments in subprocess and report back.

Comment: Maybe you should use [communicate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html?highlight=subprocess#subprocess.Popen.communicate) to look what`s the output of the subprocess

Comment: Here's a link to an explanation : <https://stackoverflow.com/a/16770371/9802108> and a way to manipulate stdout

Comment: Thanks I will have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by finding a way to call the function without subprocess. I think the issue may have related to default arguments not being set when it is executed through python and hence why below I have had to specify so many arguments.

Code:

```
from csvtotable import convert

content = convert.convert("C:\\Users\\admin\\Google Drive\\test1743.csv",delimiter=",",quotechar='"',display_length=-1,overwrite=False,serve=False,pagination=True,virtual_scroll=1000, no_header=False, export=True, export_options=["copy","csv","json","print"])
convert.save("C:\\Users\\admin\\Google Drive\\test1743.html",content)
```

Note that the argument names had to be changed where they had a `-` in the name. I just changed any instance e.g. `display-length` to `display_length` in convert.py