# python - Auto input typekeys to cmd process that has admin privileges - Using pywinauto

Tags: python, cmd, process, automation, pywinauto

I have a cmd process running with admin rights. 
I need to be able to automate some commands. Example echo Testing

MUST connect to existing Admin cmd process. (The cmd must be launched from here Location: C:\windows\system32\ComputerDefaults.exe).

Currently i can connect to a cmd process with normal rights and send code.

```
from pywinauto import Application


app = Application().connect(process = 16364)
dlg = app.top_window_()
dlg.TypeKeys('hello world')
```

However i can not connect to my cmd with admin rights. The window flashes but no command is entered.

New to coding :) Any help would be awesome!

Comment: I have more info here about my problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56606850/python-send-command-to-an-already-running-cmd

Comment: Latest pywinauto 0.6.6 should even raise an exception while connecting to admin process. You have to restart your own Python script with admin rights. See how it should look: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42787309/3648361

Comment: Anyway you have to disable UAC in Windows settings. Because UAC confirmation window can't be automated by OS design.