# Run a Fortran exe in Python

Tags: python-3.x, fortran

I am facing with an automation problem in Python. I am pretty new in using the subprocess module that I intend to use for this task. I am working with Python 3.8 and Windows 10. I have a .exe program that I want to run inside a python script. With the following commands:

```py
import sys, string, os, subprocess
from subprocess import PIPE, Popen, STDOUT, STARTUPINFO
s = Popen("my_fortran_code.exe", stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell = True)
```

I successfully start the executable Fortran code but, after that, the code needs some user inputs from the keyboard interactively. I tried to pass the inputs using communicate as follows:

```py
out = s.communicate(input=b'1\n0\n1\nfile_name\n')[0]
```

but the Fortran code doesn't receive the inputs.
Some suggestions about this problem?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: What does the Fortran program look like?  What ports are you using for input?

Comment: Also have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16768290/understanding-popen-communicate/16770371#16770371

Comment: My Fortran code uses msflib to open a gui. So, the user have to give the inputs interactively without using the command window. I expected that this task would be possibile by communicate but it doesn't work... what do you mean with ports?

Comment: Do you use write(*,fmt) or write(6,fmt).  6 would be the port.  What numbers are you using?  If running standalone, do they write to the screen?

Comment: The Fortran code uses write(*,*) and it writes to the screen if I run it standalone.