# How to run several python scripts in one file concurrently?

Tags: python, concurrency, process, multiprocessing

I want to run several python scripts from the main file and make them work in parallel.
I would like to print their outputs in a console if it is possible.
It's better to run them in different processes to be able to operate them (terminate, stop, etc).

I tried to use subprocess module but it does not print the scripts outputs and does not run the scripts concurrently.
The:

```
import subprocess
p1 = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, "first.py"])
p1.communicate()
p2 = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, "second.py"])
p2.communicate()
```

does not run both files but only one.

I tried to use module `multiprocessing` but it does not allow you to execute files.
The:

```
import multiprocessing
def run(file_path):
    exec(open(file_path).read())
p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=run, args=(file_path,))
```

is not an option because it executes file in the current file but I want to run this the same way as if this file was run separately.

I thought I can import `main` function from the executable files and call it in different processes but I do not know how to do it. And I am not sure it is a good solution because the `main` function is not supposed to be called from another file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is `Popen.communicate()` waits for the process to finish, then returns output to stdout. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16768290/understanding-popen-communicate).

Try using [threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) to thread each subprocess and run them in parallel.

```py
import subprocess
from threading import Thread

def run_file(filename):
  p1 = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, filename])
  p1.communicate()

t1 = Thread(target=lambda:run_file("first.py"))
t2 = Thread(target=lambda:run_file("second.py"))

t1.start()
t2.start()
```

This will not ensure that `first.py` necessary will run before `second.py` however, but by the nature of the question I would assume that does not matter.

Comment: Thanks, it works! I also tried to import the module with import lib and it works too but, as I said above, I am not sure it is an elegant solution to use `main` function inside another code.