# writing large amount of data to stdin

Tags: python, subprocess

I am writing a large amount of data to stdin.

How do i ensure that it is not blocking?

```
p=subprocess.Popen([path],stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
p.stdin.write('A very very very large amount of data')
p.stdin.flush()
output = p.stdout.readline()
```

It seems to hang at `p.stdin.write()` after i read a large string and write to it.

I have a large corpus of files which will be written to stdin sequentially(>1k files)

So what happens is that i am running a loop

```
#this loop is repeated for all the files
for stri in lines:
p=subprocess.Popen([path],stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
p.stdin.write(stri)
output = p.stdout.readline()
#do some processing
```

It somehow hangs at file no. 400. The file is a large file with long strings.

I do suspect its a blocking issue.

This only happens if i iterate from 0 to 1000. However, if i were to start from file 400, the error would not happen

Comment: Looks like you need to [`select`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/select.html#select.select).

Comment: Do you want to avoid it blocking at all, or just worried about a deadlock when the process's output fills up the `stdout` pipe before you finish writing to the `stdin` pipe? I think `p.communicate` will fix the deadlock, but it still will block until all the input has been sent (it just uses threads to buffer in memory whatever is coming back at the same time).

Comment: @DanD. Hi could you explain further. I do not seem to get the documentation

Comment: @Blckknght Maybe i should explain my situation further

Comment: What does the program you're running print out its stdout? You seem to be reading a single line back for each line you write, but could the program be printing more than that? Similarly, does it read your full input line before starting to write its response line, or does it work on shorter bits of data (e.g. byte by byte)?

Comment: Yes i am writing a single string to an engine to be processed and waiting for the output before moving on to the next line. It waits for the whole newline to be processed before moving on or i should say it has to read the full string before any processing can be done

Comment: @aceminer: I understand, my question was about the program on the other end. Does it sometimes return two or more lines for a single input line, or is it guaranteed to only ever return one for one? Similarly, does it operate on the input as a byte stream, or does it buffer the whole line you're sending before starting to respond? If the former of either of these, you'll probably need to use threading or some similar situation (maybe `p.communicate` with a timeout if you're using Python 3.3+) on your end to make sure you're reading the response at the same time you're writing.

Comment: @Blckknght The program on the other end also returns only a single string at any one time. The string from my python program will be encoded in utf8 and likewise the return string from the program will also be encoded in utf8. I am using python 2.7.9

Comment: @aceminer I've added a threaded solution from which you can start out if you haven't yet done something like this before. The threaded hack is easier to implement than the one that uses `select` and works on windows too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To avoid the deadlock in a portable way, write to the child in a separate thread:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from threading import Thread

def pump_input(pipe, lines):
    with pipe:
        for line in lines:
            pipe.write(line)

p = Popen(path, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, bufsize=1)
Thread(target=pump_input, args=[p.stdin, lines]).start()
with p.stdout:
    for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, b''): # read output
        print line,
p.wait()
```

See [Python: read streaming input from subprocess.communicate()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2715847/4279)