# Python child process doesn't seem to function

Tags: python, process

I run this python file to spawn a process:

```
import os
import pwd
import subprocess
import sys


p = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'process_script.py'],
                     cwd="/execute",
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                     stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

process_script.py looks like this:

```
import time
import random
import string
import helper

#

def run():
    while True:
        filename = "/execute/" + "".join([random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for j in range(8)]) + ".txt"

        helper.execute(f"echo foo > {filename}")

        time.sleep(10)

#

run()
```

[EDIT] In fact ps shows no other processess, so it looks like the thread terminates... but how and why?

If I run process_script.py directly, the files are created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in Popen child process dies when the parent exits you can add `p.wait()` at the end of your first script to prevent parent from exiting.
also this link is useful check it out!
[subprocess gets killed even with nohup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37118991/subprocess-gets-killed-even-with-nohup)

Comment: Is it possible to keep that process open even when the parent is killed?

Comment: in the provided link, they discussed on this usecase