# How to run nohup command from Python script?

Tags: python, nohup

I have a simple question. I have tried to search for a solution but there are no answers which would explain what I need.

The question is:
How do I start a `nohup` command from Python? Basically the idea is, that I have a Python script which prepares my environment and I need it to launch multiple scripts with `nohup` commands. How do I start a `nohup` command like `nohup python3 my_script.py &` from within a running Python script to have that nohup command running even after I log out?

Thank you

Comment: did you check this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37118991/subprocess-gets-killed-even-with-nohup

Comment: In general, `nohup` is useless even in bash -- it does nothing you can't do just with some redirections and potentially the shell `disown` builtin (which has, and needs, no Python equivalent). There's no reason to use it in Python; none whatsoever.

Comment: `subprocess.Popen(['python3', 'my_script.py'], stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL, stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL, start_new_session=True)` -- replace the `subprocess.DEVNULL`s for stdout and stderr with pointers to a file if you want (`nohup`'s own default is `nohup.out`, but you can call it anything you want).

Comment: (that said, if your goal is to start a service, the right way to do that is to go through your operating system's init system -- systemd has a concept of transient user services, if that's what you want; whereas if you want to emulate a _system_ service, the advantages of setting it up through systemd are even stronger).

Comment: Thank you everyone for your replies. @CharlesDuffy what do you suggest then for executing a Python script, from Python script, to run in the background endlessly?

Comment: @neisor, I gave you a line of code in my very second comment that is _exactly_ what I suggest, if your requirements are genuine and unavoidable. I'd need to know more context (what your script does, when and by what it's started, when if ever it's supposed to be _re_started, etc etc) to determine if "genuine and unavoidable" is true.

Comment: Remember, `SIGHUP` is sent to processes _using a terminal_ when that terminal closes, but when you use `</dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1` (which that `stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL`, `stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL` and `stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL` do), you're then opting out of having the new process you start have any file descriptors connecting it to the terminal. And then when you add `start_new_session=True`, you're taking it out of the process group for the parent, so it no longer gets included when something tries to signal the parent's group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need `nohup` -- not even in shell, and even less so in Python. It does the following things:

- Configures the HUP signal to be ignored (rarely relevant: if a process has no handles on a TTY it isn't going to be notified when that TTY exits regardless; the shell only propagates signals to children in interactive mode, not when running scripts).
- If stdout is a terminal, redirects it to `nohup.out`
- If stderr is a terminal, redirects it to wherever stdout was already redirected.
- Redirects stdin to `/dev/null`

That's it. There's no reason to use `nohup` to do any of those things; they're all trivial to do without it:

- `</dev/null` redirects stdin from `/dev/null` in shell; `stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL` does so in Python.
- `>nohup.out` redirects stdout to `nohup.out` in shell; `stdout=open('nohup.out', 'w')` does so in Python.
- `2>&1` makes stderr go to the same place as stdout in shell; `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT` does so in Python.

Because your process isn't attached to the terminal by virtue of the above redirections, it won't implicitly get a HUP when that terminal closes. If you're worried about a signal being sent to the parent's entire process group, however, you can avoid that by splitting off the child into a separate one:

- The `subprocess.Popen` argument `start_new_session=True` splits the child process into a separate group from the parent in Python, so a parent sent to the process group of the parent as a whole will not be received by the child.
- Adding a `preexec_fn` with `signal.signal(signal.SIGHUP, signal.SIG_IGN)` is even more explicit that the child should by default ignore a SIGHUP even if one is received.

---

Putting this all together might look like (if you really do want logs to go to a file named `nohup.out` -- I would suggest picking a better name):

```
import subprocess, signal
subprocess.Popen(['python3', 'my_script.py'],
                 stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL,
                 stdout=open('nohup.out', 'w'),
                 stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
                 start_new_session=True,
                 preexec_fn=(lambda: signal.signal(signal.SIGHUP, signal.SIG_IGN)))
```

Comment: Thank you for your extensive explanation. I'm still a bit confused on how to proceed though. Would you, please, add a short example Python code on how to create the equivalent of `nohup` in Python? Thank you very much

Comment: @neisor Refer the documentation for `subprocess.Popen `. The arguments to provide are listed out in this answer

Comment: Thank you very much! I appreciate your extensive explanation and help.

Comment: @DanNagle, ...why add an explanation of a bug in the code, vs just proposing an edit that fixes that bug? (There's no reasonable interpretation that that was by intent, because the prose explanation above the code _describes_ `signal.SIGHUP` as the correct thing).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy My edit was to move the added remark out of the code fragment.

Comment: ...funny; that remark's addition is attributed to "Community", so afaict there's no knowing where it originated.