# Passing a single variable from one python program to another program

Tags: python, python-2.7, raspberry-pi, gpio

I know this has been asked around but everytime the example is different or more complex than what I would like to do so here goes.

First.py

```
value = 10 #This variable should go to the Second script
```

Second.py

```
newdata = value #This variable should come from the First script, 10
```

So all I want to do it pass a SINGLE variable to another python that is running independently. Please I do not want to pass all the variables from the First script to the next or call the entire second script as I have seen some examples. I am running these two scripts on the Raspberry Pi and the first script is reading some sensor data while the second scripts takes that data and further computes it. Lots of variables are used from the first script so I really don't want to pass everything, only the ones I want.

Also I would like v2.7 if that makes any difference.

Thanks

Here is my code: {The variable that I want to pass to Second.py is temp}

First.py

```
# External module imports
import time
import os
import datetime
import MySQLdb

os.system('sudo modprobe w1-gpio')
os.system('sudo modprobe w1-therm')

# Connect to mysql
db=MySQLdb.connect("localhost","zikmir","gforce","temp_database")
cursor=db.cursor()

while True:
    # Initialization
    sensor= "/sys/bus/w1/devices/28-011620ee98ee/w1_slave"
    # Open the file for sensor
    file = open(sensor) 
    # Read all of the text in the file. 
    text = file.read()
    # Close the file now that the text has been read. 
    file.close() 
    # Split the text with new lines (\n) and select the second line.
    second_line = text.split("\n")[1]  
    # Split the line into words, referring to the spaces, and select the 10th word (counting from 0).
    temp_data = second_line.split(" ")[9]
    # The first two characters are "t=", so get rid of those and convert the temperature from a string to a number.
    temp = float(temp_data[2:])
    # Put the decimal point in the right place and display it. 
    temp = temp / 1000
    # Display time
    t= datetime.datetime.now()
    print t,temp
    # Push data into mySQL
    sql = "INSERT INTO time_temp VALUES(now(),%s)"
    cursor.execute (sql,(temp,))
    db.commit()
    # Wait 5 seconds
    import seven_segment
    seven_segment.getdata(temp)
    time.sleep(5)
```

Second.py

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

# GPIO ports for the 7seg pins
segments =  (11,2,23,8,7,10,18,25)
# 7seg_segment_pins (11,7,4,2,1,10,5,3) +  100R inline

for segment in segments:
    GPIO.setup(segment, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.output(segment, 0)

# GPIO ports for the digit 0-3 pins 
digits = (22,27,17)
# 7seg_digit_pins (12,9,8) digits 0-3 respectively

for digit in digits:
    GPIO.setup(digit, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.output(digit, 1)

num = {' ':(0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
    '0':(1,1,1,1,1,1,0),
    '1':(0,1,1,0,0,0,0),
    '2':(1,1,0,1,1,0,1),
    '3':(1,1,1,1,0,0,1),
    '4':(0,1,1,0,0,1,1),
    '5':(1,0,1,1,0,1,1),
    '6':(1,0,1,1,1,1,1),
    '7':(1,1,1,0,0,0,0),
    '8':(1,1,1,1,1,1,1),
    '9':(1,1,1,1,0,1,1)}

try:
    while True:
        def getdata(temp):

            n = temp

        s = str(n).rjust(3)

        for digit in range(3):
            for loop in range(0,7):
                GPIO.output(segments[loop], num[s[digit]][loop])
                if (int(time.ctime()[18:19])%2 == 0) and (digit == 1):
                    GPIO.output(25, 1)
                else:
                    GPIO.output(25, 0)
            GPIO.output(digits[digit], 0)
            time.sleep(0.001)
            GPIO.output(digits[digit], 1)
finally:
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

I have it working on a test code but not in my main code for some reason, Here is what I tried and I was successfully able to pass the data:

firsttest.py

```
value = 1000

def main():
    print("abc")
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

secondtest.py

```
from firsttest import value
recieved = value
print recieved
```

The out put is indeed 1000, and I only have to run the secondtest.py and the firsttest.py gets executed automatically. But when I run my original code, the first.py does execute but I'm not having any output from the second.py
I don't know if this is raspberry pi related since I'm using multiple GPIO's or if this is a programming error.

Any help would be amazing. My worse solution would be to make the first.py output to a text file and have the second.py read it from there, hopefully that wont also contradict since both scripts will be trying to use it at the same time?

Comment: import the Second.py call one of its function and pass the value

Comment: @nishantkumar perhaps can you elaborate with an example code? Thanks.

Comment: Please indent your code correctly.

Comment: Also, I suspect that this update totally invaludates my answer. @nishant-kumar nailed it, barring a small omission.

Comment: Still waiting for you to fix the indentation in your code so I can see where your while loop ends, among other things...

Comment: One more question: when you say "running independently", do you mean that they are in two separate Python processes? If so, could you clarify that in the question? Because in that case, all of the answers are completely invalid and you have to do something at the OS level either with shared memory or pipes.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Fixed it! Please any suggestions on how I would be doing this? Any yes they are different programs running on the same Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Thanks. That's much better. It's a non trivial solution that will have nothing to do with imports in this case. I'll sleep on this and write you an answer tomorrow morning.

Comment: @MadPhysicist, you are truly a life saver! Thanks so far, I will check for your post tomorrow as well!

Answer (score 3):

Use an import like this:

file1.py:

```
value = 1

def main():
     print("execute only if called directly")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

and in file2.py:

```
from file1 import value
```

Make sure to have both files in one package (directory must contain an    `__init__.py` file). Of course you can also access the file if it is in another package.

Alternatively, you can write a get_value() function in file1.py that returns the requested value and import this function:

```
from file1 import get_value
value = get_value()
```

If temp is a variable that is updated frequently (as I suspect looking at your code), you could do either

1) write a function (e.g. `First.read_temp()`) that reads the temperature once and then import and use this function in Second.py or

2) fetch the latest value for temp from the database (if the time delay does not matter).

Comment: Nice answer, but I am beginning to think that OP is talking about cross-process communication and not just importing parts of one module into another.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I hear what you are saying. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Start `second.py` with `from first import value`. This will import only that one name into your namespace.

Keep in mind that the entire script `first` will have to be run to make this work. So if you have any runnable code in your script, make sure that it is guarded be a line like [`if __name__ == '__main__'`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/419163/2988730).

Comment: I have actually never used import guard! Can you give an example? From what I understand is that the First.py has to be run which will execute the Second.py by it self?

Comment: Sorry, I just realized that's the wrong term. I'll expand my answer in a few minutes when I get off mobile. In the mean time, I've updated with a link.

Answer (score 1):

### INTRO

This is going to be a bit long, so I have written an intro.

Since you are trying to get two independent processes to communicate with each other, the problem can not be solved with just imports. One process has to write the data, the other has to read it. You have a number of options available for doing this. Here are three, but keep in mind that there are other ways:

1. Have one process start the other and use the [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module to communicate between them.
2. Use [Unix Domain Sockets](https://pymotw.com/2/socket/uds.html), which are like regular sockets, but can be accessed via a named file on a Linux (or other Unix implementation) machine. This would use the [`socket`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html) module.
3. Use a shared memory implementation to just write the value in a shared piece of memory. As far as I know there is no built-in module for doing this with processes that are completely independent of each other.

Of the three methods described above, the first is the most portable, but you have to start one script from the other. I can't imagine this being a huge problem for you given the code that is shown.

The second method only works on Unix-like systems, which I don't expect to be a problem on a Raspberry Pi. It allows you to run the processes completely independently: they only have to share the name of the socket between them, and you can actually guarantee that it will be the same using imports. I will not go into this method because it is probably overkill for your case.

I am not aware of any way to implement the third option using only builtin modules. You could use a library like [shm](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/shm/0.1), but I will not go into any detail about this method.

### Code

Before I explain how to implement items 1 and 2, I would like to propose restructuring your code a bit to make the transition process easier. I like that you have a `getdata` function already planned in `Second.py`. However, there are a couple more changes that I would suggest to make this process easier:

**First.py**:

```
# External module imports
import time
import os
import datetime
import MySQLdb

import seven_segment

def main():
    os.system('sudo modprobe w1-gpio')
    os.system('sudo modprobe w1-therm')

    # Connect to mysql
    db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","zikmir","gforce","temp_database")
    cursor = db.cursor()

    # Initialization
    sensor = "/sys/bus/w1/devices/28-011620ee98ee/w1_slave"

    while True:
        # Open the file for sensor
        with open(sensor) as file: 
            # Read all of the text in the file. 
            text = file.read()
        # Split the text with new lines (\n) and select the second line.
        second_line = text.split("\n")[1]  
        # Split the line into words, referring to the spaces, and select the 10th word (counting from 0).
        temp_data = second_line.split(" ")[9]
        # The first two characters are "t=", so get rid of those and convert the temperature from a string to a number.
        temp = float(temp_data[2:])
        # Put the decimal point in the right place and display it. 
        temp = temp / 1000
        # Display time
        print datetime.datetime.now(), temp
        # Send temperature over for further processing
        write_out(temp)
        # Push data into mySQL
        sql = "INSERT INTO time_temp VALUES(now(),%s)"
        cursor.execute (sql,(temp,))
        db.commit()
        # Wait 5 seconds
        seven_segment.getdata(temp)
        time.sleep(5)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Second.py**:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

# GPIO ports for the 7seg pins
segments = (11,2,23,8,7,10,18,25)
# 7seg_segment_pins (11,7,4,2,1,10,5,3) + 100R inline

for segment in segments:
    GPIO.setup(segment, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.output(segment, 0)

# GPIO ports for the digit 0-3 pins 
digits = (22,27,17)
# 7seg_digit_pins (12,9,8) digits 0-3 respectively

for digit in digits:
    GPIO.setup(digit, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.output(digit, 1)

num = {
    ' ': (0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
    '0': (1,1,1,1,1,1,0),
    '1': (0,1,1,0,0,0,0),
    '2': (1,1,0,1,1,0,1),
    '3': (1,1,1,1,0,0,1),
    '4': (0,1,1,0,0,1,1),
    '5': (1,0,1,1,0,1,1),
    '6': (1,0,1,1,1,1,1),
    '7': (1,1,1,0,0,0,0),
    '8': (1,1,1,1,1,1,1),
    '9': (1,1,1,1,0,1,1),
}

try:
    while True:
        s = str(get_temp()).rjust(3)
        for pos, digit in enumerate(s):
            for loop in range(7):
                GPIO.output(segments[loop], num[digit][loop])
                flag = (int(time.time()) % 2 == 0) and (pos == 1)
                GPIO.output(25, flag)
            GPIO.output(digits[pos], 0)
            time.sleep(0.001)
            GPIO.output(digits[pos], 1)
finally:
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

Most of the changes are cleanups like defining constant items outside the loop. The key additions are the calls to `write_out` in `First.py` and `get_temp` in `Second.py`.

Also notice that the functionality of `First` is now within a `main` function, which only gets called when `__name__ == '__main__'`. This will allow you to run `First.py` as a script from the command line just as you did before. When you do `import First` inside `Second.py`, it will not run all of the code, just define the constants that you have outside of `main`.

### Subprocess Method

With this method, `First.py` would have to start `Second.py` or vice versa. I will go with the first approach because it just seems a bit simpler. Either way, the standard output of `First` will go to the standard input of `Second`. You could change `First.py` to read as follows:

```
import subprocess, sys

...

def main(proc):
   ...
   write_out(proc, temp)
   ...

...

def write_out(proc, temp):
    print(temp, file=proc.stdin)
    proc.stdin.flush() # Necessary if you want to have real-time updates

if __name__ == '__main__':
    second = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, 'Second.py'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
    main(second)
```

Here, first kicks off `Second.py` and pipes the temperature values to `Second`'s stdin. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37058548/2988730) is an answer that is relevant. `First.main` now has to accept a subprocess as an argument, which needs to be passed to `write_out`.

`Second.py` does not need any modifications in this case: just a definition of `get_temp` that reads from stdin:

```
def get_temp():
    temp = float(sys.in.readline())
```

### Conclusion

Given the amount of work you have to do to make this work, you may want to consider another approach entirely. Perhaps you could just define a function that does the additional processing in `Second.py` (similarly to what I did with `main` in `First.py`). You could then call the function in a background thread from `First.py` every time you got a new temperature reading. This would make your code much simpler and easier to deal with. Assuming that your function was called `process_temp`, you could do something like the following in `First.py`:

```
import threading

...

def write_out(temp):
    thread = threading.Thread(target=Second.process_temp, args=(temp,))
    thread.start()

...
```