# How can I Make multiple asynchronous call to python cgi script

Tags: apache, python-3.x, cgi

I have a CGI form which takes a CSV sheet and email and calls two individual python scripts which run in the background. These take about 15 minutes to execute. I want to make an asynchronous call to these scripts so that I can display some message and prevent apache timeout.

Here is my code

```
import os
import cgi, cgitb
import csv
import sys
import subprocess
import io

cgitb.enable()
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
filedata = form['file']
filecontent = filedata.file.read().splitlines()
email=form.getvalue('email_address')

email = str(email)



subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, 'giw.py', str(email)], shell=False,
stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None, close_fds=True)


subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, 'mailer.py', str(email)], shell=False,
stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None, close_fds=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:-

[Run background process in Python and do NOT wait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37058013/run-background-process-in-python-and-do-not-wait)

```
import subprocess
import sys

subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, 'giw.py', str(email)],  stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT);
```