# Execute processes or files in the background (Python)

Tags: python

Is it possible for the `os` or the `subprocess` modules in Python to run a file or a task in the background?

Say I were to integrate certain keystrokes such that while the script is running, those certain keystrokes will trigger a certain `subprocess.call(...)` than shall *open up only in the background* i.e, without moving me out of my active window.

Comment: Yes it is definitely possible, but i don't have much experience with subprocess. You may find this helpful : https://stackoverflow.com/a/37059478/14976549

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I run an external command asynchronously from Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/636561/how-can-i-run-an-external-command-asynchronously-from-python)

Comment: @AlbinPaul I'll check that out in a bit and then accordingly answer your suggestion. Much thanks!